# Method of CI 3 doesn't work on php 5.6 version but works on php 7

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am using Codeigniter 3.0.6. And i am developing on my local server and my php version is already php7. It works well. But then i uploaded it on server that use php 5.6. Then i got this error.

> ```
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'list' (T_LIST), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in /var/www/simimi/application/controllers/Student.php on line 53
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
>     Severity: Parsing Error
>
>     Message: syntax error, unexpected 'list' (T_LIST), expecting identifier (T_STRING)
>
>     Filename: controllers/Student.php
>
>     Line Number: 53
>
>     Backtrace:
> ```

Here's my controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Student extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('m_student','sdb');
        $this->load->model('m_student_profile','sdb_pro');
        $this->load->model('m_student_academic','sdb_aca');
        $this->load->model('m_student_immigration','sdb_imm');
        $this->load->model('m_student_emergency','sdb_eme');
        $this->cname = 'student';
        $this->menu = 'Student';
        $this->fitur = '';
        $this->active_user=get_nama_user();
        $this->active_username=get_username();
        $this->active_privilege=get_hak_akses();
        if(!cek_auth())
        {
            flash_err('Authorization needed.');
            redirect(base_url('auth'));
        }
        if(!cek_fitur('student_list'))
        {
            flash_err("You don't have privilege to use `{$this->menu}` feature.");
            redirect(base_url('dashboard'));
        }
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->list();
    }

    public function action($func='', $id=0)
    {
        if(!empty(trim($func)))
        {
            if(!empty($id))
                $this->$func($id);
            else if(empty($id))
                $this->$func();
        }
        else
        {
            flash_err("You don't have permission.");
            redirect(base_url($this->cname));
        }
    }

    public function list()
    {
        $data['title']='Student';
        $data['subtitle']='List';
        $data['active']='student_list';
        $this->fitur = 'List';
        $data['content']='student_list';
        $data['students']=$this->sdb->get_list();
        $this->load->view('template/template',$data);
    }
}
```

Aaaaand
It just occured to me that list isnt allowed to be a method name.  I wonder why it runs on php7 though.

Comment: /var/www/simimi/application/controllers/Student.php open the fine look @line 53. CAn you please post the code

Comment: already added it @KARTHISRV but i think my controller is fine because my program is working well on my server that use php7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that `list` is a reserved keyword for PHP.  Prior to PHP 7, you could not use these as method names.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

> As of PHP 7.0.0 these keywords are allowed as as property, constant, and method names of classes, interfaces and traits, except that class may not be used as constant name.

Comment: Thank you. I just realized it too. I was panicked. 

Answer (score 0):

Turns out list isnt allowed to be a method name.  I changed the method name and it works well now. Though i still wonder why it works well on php7.